# IIS 7 - Can you hide alias from url?

Tags: iis-7

Can you hide alias from URL?

I have an MVC web app I deployed last night. Added an application to the default site.

Currently I have site.com/alias/controller/action.

I'd like to have the url: site.com/controller/action.

Any suggestions appreciated.